# TFS 2012 Build not deploying

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, webdeploy

I have a TFS build created. It builds fine and deploys the website to the drop folder.  But the settings I am putting into the build parameters to make it webdeploy seem to be ignored.  The build is being compiled with the default Relase|Any CPU configuration and there is no mention in the logs to indicate that it is even attempting to deploy.

Any ideas on where to start investigating the problem?

```
/p:Configuration=ecrCI 
/p:Platform="Any CPU" 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://mywebserver:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=myrUrl 
/p:UserName=ecr 
/p:Password=xxxx
/p:IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 (or what ever version of VS you are using).  I think I have seen some issues around this before.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be along the right lines with this.
TFSBuild is running C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

and its not picking up the references to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.dll   where I think the /p:DeployOnBuild=true code is located.

Adding /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 doesn't seem to make any difference to this though.

Comment: I can't install VS2012 on the server though because its windows 2008.  I have tried copying the files over manually, but possibly this is not good enough and it needs installing properly?

Comment: You need to install VS on the machine for this to work properly.